# WebSockets: Can connect but cannot subscribe to channel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, redis, flutter, actioncable

I have a rails API-only app running in nginx with passenger. I'm trying to use Action Cable to set up a simple chat application in Flutter but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

I am able to connect using the following:

```
 channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("wss://my.domain/cable")
```

and see the following in my production.log when that happens:

```
Started GET "/cable" for [redacted] at 2019-03-14 19:44:09 +0000
Started GET "/cable" [WebSocket] for [redacted] at 2019-03-14 19:44:09 +0000
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Doorkeeper::AccessToken Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `oauth_access_tokens`.* FROM `oauth_access_tokens` WHERE `oauth_access_tokens`.`token` = '[redacted]' LIMIT 1
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vYWdlbnQyNHg3L1VzZXIvMg)
```

So the connection seems to be made and successfully upgraded

I am then sending a subscribe command

```
channel.sink.add(json.encode({
  "command": "subscribe",
  "identifier": {"channel": "ConversationChannel", "conversation_id": "${conversation.id}"}
}));
```

I'm not sure if I should be seeing anything in the log files after this command is executed, but I don't. Nothing happens and there is no indication of any error in my production.log or my nginx error log. I set up some logging in the subscribe method of the ConversationChannel so it would at least output something to the production log when it is called, so I could test if it's at least even calling the subscribe command

```
class ConversationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
    def subscribed
      Rails.logger.info "test conversation subscribe"
      reject && return unless current_user
      stream_from "conversation_#{params[:conversation_id]}_channel"
    end

    ...

end
```

but this does not appear in production.log so it would seem that the subscription command is not getting to where it is supposed to go.

I then tried using dart WebSocket using the code located [here](https://pastebin.com/0MkupDaD), which came from [a conversation on github regarding connection states](https://github.com/dart-lang/web_socket_channel/issues/16), to see if I could determine if the connection was coming back okay.

When I run that code with my domain I see the same successful connection in the production.log, but the connection actually times out with `onerror TimeoutException after 0:00:15.000000: Future not completed` which seems to indicate that the connection actually *doesn't* succeed after all, despite what it says in the log file.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: hi do you find solution for this ?

Comment: No I haven't. I just abandoned the feature in my application that this was intended to support. I have a feeling it was a server level configuration issue of some sort but I have no clues as to what. I'm in the middle of deploying a new server set up so I plan to try it from scratch there. If I do end up finding a solution I'll update my question to let others know.

Comment: you could use [action_cable](https://pub.dev/packages/action_cable) to work on flutter, maybe this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67453440/3330650) can you help.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember, when you're attempting to connect to a channel, your identifier has to be JSON stringified, as well as your whole JSON object. Take a look at this link:

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/talking-to-actioncable-without-rails

In particular:

```
const msg = {
  command: 'subscribe',
  identifier: JSON.stringify({
    channel: 'SomeChannel',
  }),
};
socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
```

Rails does the whole JSON parsing in the backend. See if this helps you out. I've had similar issues like this before, when attempting to connect the WebSockets, without the usage of their ActionCable npm library.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to respond!

Yes I've seen that method used in most of the tutorials I've looked at. I tried that initially with no success and have tried it again now with the same level of success.

It also appears wrong to me as in such examples they are actually encoding the identifier object twice - so you end up with `{"command":"subscribe","identifier":"{\"channel\":\"ConversationChannel\",\"conversation_id\":\"2\"}"}` - notice the identifier portion is string escaped but the command portion is not. If we take the resulting string and attempt to decode it, it fails.

Comment: @MarkRawlingson, Did you get the conversation_id in subscribed method correctly?